# Navigation Drawer Menu, Item Color

Tags: java, android, menu

when I open a navigation menu drawer project with Android Studio, it comes in Gray by default. I couldn't change them. How do I make color as in the picture?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfUPD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your NaviagtigationView tag has a couple properties you can use.

```
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Your.Style"
app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
```